# Android - How to create login and store access token from Json?

Tags: android, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have written an API for my Rails application which does the following there operations as of now.

1.Login with email and password. The access token of the user is returned.

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"email":"testtesttest@test.com", "password":"testtest"}}' 'http://rails-tutorial-sumai.c9.io/api/sessions'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
etag: W/"dab624d9e5b16d1dd447605c6d0dfde9"
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: 36d360e0-765f-410c-b962-d0780f1e5eab
x-runtime: 0.097109
transfer-encoding: chunked
server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.4/2014-10-27)
date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 23:50:24 GMT

{"id":2,"access_token":"6148e8897c25b8b16ab5b938b5e481d3bb7faf825613a5fa","user_id":14,"created_at":"2015-04-21T22:42:51.656Z","updated_at":"2015-04-21T22:42:51.656Z"}
$
```

2.Display all users using access token.

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="6148e8897c25b8b16ab5b938b5e481d3bb7faf825613a5fa"' -i  'http://rails-tutorial-sumai.c9.io/api/users'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
etag: W/"bfc3aeabca5e1f1d8deaa9f9bcb1b557"
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: e46ed53b-9987-4ad4-b7d6-a1ef6d00fd14
x-runtime: 0.029815
transfer-encoding: chunked
server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.4/2014-10-27)
date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 23:50:30 GMT

[{"id":14,"name":"testtest","email":"testtesttest@test.com","created_at":"2015-04-21T22:21:36.268Z","updated_at":"2015-04-21T22:34:32.548Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$dv3LVipJCyy/O8mIufjrMuWa0YBmL68BWOJciY27Uzz9euBILtJUO","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":true,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$1i3gmOM93MKaZ4.xMmydjOVqlYBSqecfZMyORQvM93C3.rrpK4Wgu","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-04-21T22:24:36.507Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":5,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"hehe"},{"id":1,"name":"sumar","email":"chu07@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-01-23T12:57:41.502Z","updated_at":"2015-03-28T02:53:46.438Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$xNvGKpPwspaeTd33QrTwuuLP0TesuuTmfbrUlFO7LDsWXGkf7XP7m","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":true,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$nIwWkX2X8WugscC/Yre7KeWRIzw6ecNyA5hLn/xPw9C0FyzyO6BJq","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-01-23T12:58:58.337Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test "},{"id":13,"name":"mah kumar","email":"testlmah@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-24T13:57:56.184Z","updated_at":"2015-03-24T13:58:47.267Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$oyIFQ9b.yyLQ8AMagwGNfeBE9.iXhSg/8PyoQ8fO9.ApH3ZvZ7Q/K","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$xhpJCNVDvyLqcBZC8LhgkOqTeptHEy.UGNCH.4FFGBLPalLotqPQO","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-24T13:58:23.488Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test"},{"id":12,"name":"intro kumar","email":"chutest@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-24T13:39:40.659Z","updated_at":"2015-03-24T13:51:20.796Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$2bchzMYDDCXcDKdGS7NmceOH0700NAWQnVwjr3JDSF4duPmIFtFPi","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$VDWd7wNBHbdsD7j2k1gpa.UAGcXXcibVlUYsMCPd9CJu5es6vTnDK","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-24T13:40:00.180Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test"},{"id":11,"name":"testingkumar","email":"testlama@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-24T13:23:11.249Z","updated_at":"2015-03-24T13:32:03.393Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$SAJJ4nF/uKiYHJfWmNjRG.DWbGctI4YXW3j/lfq3fFwQd3MdFU5ei","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$LAcveGkYgUDGd6kyCq2T4.ZaMDhcu1rT7YnZFcMeqf..fB22oonhm","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-24T13:23:24.477Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test"},{"id":10,"name":"Test kumar","email":"testkumar@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-24T08:00:49.896Z","updated_at":"2015-03-24T13:14:31.973Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$2CePnBtr1C2IjDGaK3USFe06JY437g2cAAKLShO4Zw9nWqA3Xdnve","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$AdvDADJ78vC0/NMysfckxeTJOGc2rxwcw2n653ySeEmlue1v2ZRbW","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-24T08:01:20.566Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test"},{"id":9,"name":"Karesh Kumar","email":"test5@test5.com","created_at":"2015-03-08T20:02:48.369Z","updated_at":"2015-03-08T20:05:46.148Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$6iTjYf.07juB92ha0UCUn.jpUWca.y.VTDRZQ3H1s1pspVvArBFw6","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$DhyOJ86NqhCly8GfnM44/OPN78mlgGxqXQ29CGvoaYR7xCO5EE68y","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-08T20:03:16.968Z","reset_digest":"$2a$10$wNXmFgm8BECjybD8eE4D7eYyGioHIt/qBVmBwQ7SrRpOKn4/yOTw2","reset_sent_at":"2015-03-08T20:04:44.748Z","avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"hey"},{"id":5,"name":"testtest","email":"test1@test1.com","created_at":"2015-03-08T19:46:06.830Z","updated_at":"2015-03-08T19:47:30.477Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$2aiBrrVNUjBAXICo6tNTU./O.p18/4RQ1gKU22f2/A3I1t6y0byNq","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$R1KDahoJDTJqdd6ND0FO8eDCOYzR4Qk1tffifm5qFpTfr7wcGF2bi","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-08T19:46:32.225Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"testtest"},{"id":4,"name":"Mahesh Kumar","email":"testing@test.com","created_at":"2015-02-16T14:32:41.566Z","updated_at":"2015-02-16T14:33:56.728Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$kwjZJVg5EDC52L6aeZeV8urOU/.mlL6ZAGK.CR5acNpjm3SvAcr9y","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1978-05-10T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":true,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$xOS01HD6vICt2PWrDtJhYOwXissxrbtD4h9kqNr2AfBss.EzsSzC.","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-02-16T14:33:18.257Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":12,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test"}] 
$
```

3.Display a single user using access_token

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="6148e8897c25b8b16ab5b938b5e481d3bb7faf825613a5fa"' -i  'http://rails-tutorial-sumai.c9.io/api/users/12'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
etag: W/"0c556c7850e78074ec37aa308526595d"
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: 4157a358-fd0d-4603-a699-2918793da586
x-runtime: 0.053024
transfer-encoding: chunked
server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.4/2014-10-27)
date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 23:50:41 GMT

{"id":12,"name":"intro kumar","email":"chutest@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-24T13:39:40.659Z","updated_at":"2015-03-24T13:51:20.796Z","password_digest":"$2a$10$2bchzMYDDCXcDKdGS7NmceOH0700NAWQnVwjr3JDSF4duPmIFtFPi","remember_digest":null,"admin":false,"date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","is_female":false,"activation_digest":"$2a$10$VDWd7wNBHbdsD7j2k1gpa.UAGcXXcibVlUYsMCPd9CJu5es6vTnDK","activated":true,"activated_at":"2015-03-24T13:40:00.180Z","reset_digest":null,"reset_sent_at":null,"avatar_file_name":null,"avatar_content_type":null,"avatar_file_size":null,"avatar_updated_at":null,"country_id":1,"cover_file_name":null,"cover_content_type":null,"cover_file_size":null,"cover_updated_at":null,"intro":"test","microposts":[]}
$
```

I am very new to Android programming. I have created a very simple android app using Android studio with just textview and button by following certain online tutorials.
Now I would like to create a login page and display all the users using the API I created for my rails application.

Can someone kindly point to resources which will help me login and then display all the users?
Thanks.